# Is possible to run only one test of GoogleTest, instead of to run all tests (Run_all_test)?

Tags: googletest

I need to execute only one of tests that I created. However, I didn't find how to run it, because I only  found "Run_all_tests".

Answer (score 9):

From the gtest [Advanced Guide](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_AdvancedGuide#Running_a_Subset_of_the_Tests):

> By default, a Google Test program runs all tests the user has defined. Sometimes, you want to run only a subset of the tests (e.g. for debugging or quickly verifying a change). If you set the GTEST_FILTER environment variable or the --gtest_filter flag to a filter string, Google Test will only run the tests whose full names (in the form of TestCaseName.TestName) match the filter.

So for example adding the flag:

```
--gtest_filter=Foo.Bar
```

will filter and disable every single tests except Foo.Bar. Other options described in the guide give more flexibility over which tests you want to have executed at runtime.

Comment: Updated link to gtest advanced guide: https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html